# Find values of $x$ so that the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Find values of $x$ so that the matrix is invertible
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
x &  0 & x \\
x &  2 &  1 \\
2x &  0 &   2x \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that a matrix is invertible if determinant is not $0$, but I don't know how to find the $x$ values. I feel is a tricky question and this matrix will not be invertible no matter which value $x$ takes, but I don't know how to prove that either.

Comment: Your feeling is correct (compare the top and bottom rows)

Comment: Even if you don't notice the first and the third row, you should be able to reduce this to $2\times2$ determinant: $\det A= 2\det\begin{pmatrix} x&x\\2x&2x\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to calculate it determinant:

$$ \det(A) = 4x^2 -4x^2 $$

Since it is always $0$ it is never invertibile.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $\forall x, R_3=2R_1\implies Rank(A)<3\implies \det(A)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

$\det(A)=\begin{vmatrix}
x &  0 & x \\
x &  2 &  1 \\
2x &  0 &   2x \\
\end{vmatrix}$
$=\begin{vmatrix}
x &  0 & x \\
x &  2 &  1 \\
0 &  0 &   0 \\
\end{vmatrix}=0$

The first step equals second step by row operations.

Answer (score 4):

If $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ are the three columns of $A$, then $C_1-\frac x2C_2=C_3-\frac12C_2$. Therefore, the columns are not linearly independent and so the matrix is not invertible (whatever $x$ is).